# ¿Cómo obtener divisores de un número de manera rápida?

Tags: python, eficiencia

¿Cómo puedo obtener todos los divisores de números grandes de forma veloz? Por ejemplo 956743235

Comment: Sube el código que hayas intentado

Comment: Divisores o factores primos? porque divisores serían las multiplicaciones de todas las combinaciones posibles de sus factores primos. Pueden ser muchas...

Comment: Divisores un ejemplo del 6 son 1 2 3 6 o del 100 son 1 2 4 5 10 20 25 50 100

Comment: Intente con un ciclo for preguntando desde el NUMERO 1 hasta (el numero del cual quiero encontrar sus divisores//2) y si su modulo es igual a 0 entonces es un divisor pero para un numero grande se tarda muchos segundos y quisiera que lo haga en menos tiempo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero vamos a calcular sus `factores primos`, estos nos ayudaran a calcular los demás factores, para ello utilice una función `criba` que mediante la `criba de eratóstenes` calcula los primeros números primos (hasta la raíz cuadrada del numero a calcular los factores).

Una vez hecho esto, calculo sus factores primos en la función de `factores_primos`, te dejo un [link](https://www.portaleducativo.net/quinto-basico/773/factores-primos) de como se calcula, no es difícil si ya tenemos los primos calculados.

Ahora viene lo difícil, lo que haremos sera mediante los factores primos sacar sus raíces, es decir para `100` sus factores primos serian `[2, 2, 5, 5]` (previamente calculados), lo que indica tener un `2` dos veces y un `5` dos veces, esos valores los pondremos en potencia y le sumamos una potencia mas es decir 2^0, 2^1, 2^2, 5^0, 5^1, 5^2 que seria `1, 2, 4` para la base 2 y `1, 5 y 25` para la base 5, y multiplicamos entre si los de una base con la otra `1 con 1`, `1 con 5`, `1 con 2`, así sucesivamente lo que daria `[1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 20, 25, 50, 100]` ya ordenados, y vuala ya tenemos los factores de 100.

Aun así habrá veces que faltaran factores solo basta con dividir los el numero entre todos estos factores, es decir en este caso dividimos `100`, sobre los factores ya calculados, que nos salen los mismos, pero habrá veces que no (como en tu caso), te dejo el código que acabo de programar no esta muy bien ordenado pero espero se entienda.

```
from math import sqrt

primos = []
fact_prim = []
def criba(num):
    global primos
    n = num
    num = int(sqrt(num))
    l = [0]*(num+1)

    for i in range(2,num+1):
        if l[i] == 0:
            primos.append(i)
        for j in range(i*2,num+1,i):
            l[j] = 1

def factores_primos(num):
    while not num in primos:
        for i in primos:
            if num%i==0:
                num //= i
                fact_prim.append(i)
                break
    fact_prim.append(num)

def main():
    num = 956743235 
    criba(num)
    factores_primos(num)
    #print ("Factores primos: ", fact_prim)
    d = dict()
    for i in fact_prim:
        d[str(i)] = d.get(str(i),0) + 1

    factores2 = set()
    factores3 = set()

    for i in d.keys():
        factores1 = set()
        for j in range(d[i]+1):
            factores1.add(int(i)**j)

        for f2 in factores2:
            for f1 in factores1:
                factores3.add(f2*f1)

        for f in factores1:
            factores2.add(f)

    respuesta = set([i for i in factores3])
    for f3 in factores3:
        respuesta.add(num//f3)
    print(sorted(respuesta))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    input()
```

Salida

```
[1, 5, 7, 31, 35, 155, 217, 593, 1085, 1487, 2965, 4151, 7435, 10409, 18383, 20755, 46097, 52045, 91915, 128681, 230485, 322679, 643405, 881791, 1613395, 4408955, 6172537, 27335521, 30862685, 136677605, 191348647, 956743235]
```

Comment: Para agilizar el calculo de números primos `menores a` podría usar algun test probabilistico de primalidad como el de Miller-Rabin, Fermat o SS, tiene un margen de error, pero aceptables como para validar un rango de numeros de posibles factores primos con confianza.

Comment: Interesante comentario, siempre he usado la criba pero los que comentas suenan bien, quedará investigar. Saludos